# as3 textarea focus event bug

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not sure how long this has existed, it seems to have just come up for the first time.
If you create a TextArea component (author or runtime) and give it focus, you'll get 3 focus events.

create a new as3 fla, drag the TextArea component into your library and paste this on frame 1.

```
import flash.events.FocusEvent;
import fl.controls.TextArea;

var field = new TextArea();
addChild(field);

var field2 = new TextArea();
field2.x = 150;

addChild(field2);
field.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
function onFocusIn(event:FocusEvent):void{
    trace(event.target);
}
```

Now click on the left field. Do you see 3 trace statements?
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried event.stopPropogation()?

Answer (score 1):

You receive multiple FocusEvents, because TextArea contains a TextInput that it controls. When you Focus on the TextArea, the focus is actually given to the TextInput and you receive a focus event for the TextArea, and another for the TextInput.

The best way to limit the number of received event is to check if the target of the event is the same that the target you actually listen.

```
function onFocusIn(event:FocusEvent):void{
    if (event.target == event.currentTarget) {
        trace(event.target); // only the focus events generated by the TextArea.
    }
}
```

**EDIT** So, I got back to the code with the issue about clicks, and the actual fix is really tricky. In fact, the source of the error was a combination of various same issues.

- First : the fact that TextArea and the inner TextField both send Event at the beginning.
- Second : After the beginning, when the TextField receive focus from a click, it is blocked by the parent.
- And Third : When the focus come from out of the swf, in your case, the focus event is send two times (dunno why).

In order to fix it correctly, I had to listen to the unknown TextField within the TextArea (instead of the TextArea itself), and keep track of the focus leaving the Stage in order to inhibit the first of the two events generated. Which gives this :

```
import flash.events.FocusEvent;
import fl.controls.TextArea;

var stageFocus:Boolean = true;

var field = new TextArea();
addChild(field);

var field2 = new TextArea();
field2.x = 150;
addChild(field2);

field.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
function onFocusIn(event:FocusEvent):void{
    if (event.target == event.currentTarget) {
        if (event.target is TextField) {
            if (stageFocus) {
                // Finally ! one event at a Time and no miss.
                trace(DisplayObject(event.target).parent); 
            } else {
                stageFocus = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        event.target.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
        field.removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
    }
}

// check if the focus leave the stage (the user clic out of the swf)
stage.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onStageFocusOut);
function onStageFocusOut(event:FocusEvent) {
    if (event.relatedObject == null) {
        stageFocus = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood that TextArea's composition of a textinput was causing 2 (3 for the first time) events, but was lost as to any logical reason why. Even worse, they don't implement a common interface that supports textual properties. I'm working on a soft keyboard so that's a pain.

I had a similar solution in the works that tests for Types specifically but I like your event.target vs event.currentTarget much better.

Comment: I tested your solution and while it is an improvement, there's still some weirdness.

    `function onFocusIn(event:FocusEvent):void{
 if(event.target == event.currentTarget){
  trace(event.target);
 }
    
    }`

The first time I click in the left field I get the trace, after selecting the other and going back I get nothing. However if I use the tab key it works each time. FocusManager is not updating who has focus or something.

Comment: Ha, you're right ! It looks like TextArea have many strange behavior. It seems that (the first time excepted), the FOCUS_IN event from the TextField is not repeated by the TextArea. I have a fix, but it is still not exactly perfect. I'll edit my post once I'm done with this.

Comment: Some very good thinking here. It's a fairly solid solution for dealing with a specific field. Well done.
However I'm dealing with a bit higher level where I'm listening to the stage for all Focus_In events and determining if it came from a TextArea or TextInput. Your use of event.relatedObject totally pointed me in the right direction. Right now I'm using this bad boy which filters out stage activation but DOES NOT WORK for tabbing.
`if(event.target.parent is TextInput || (event.target.parent is TextArea && event.target.root != event.relatedObject.parent) ) {
    trace(event.target.parent);
}`

Comment: Did you try using FocusEvent.KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE and FocusEvent.MOUSE_FOCUS_CHANGE to detect both focus source separately ? Note that those event are dispatched when focus is either given or lost.
Also, if you track the Focus for all TextInput/TextArea on Stage, wouldn't it be better to create an instances of a Tracker class and attach it to a TextField/TextInput when it is added ? That way your code on the stage can get which Text has the focus through the Tracker instances, and those instanace manage the bugs and workaround of focus management.

Comment: In my tests, Key_Focus_Change and Mouse_Focus_Change only fired on blur. This virtual keyboard is being added to an old code base for an app that has some author-time created forms and some run-time created forms. All form fields are custom classes that create a TextInput or TextArea at some point so modifying their code or hooking into the bootstrap code is a messy venture at best.
In this case it's just better to stay decoupled.

Comment: Just found that this solution also prevents you from getting the caret position in the handler as it is not set until a subsequent dispatch. ugg.